# How to call an abstract superclass method in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, abstract-class, superclass

I have an abstract handle class **Mesh**. It has several concrete subclasseses: **Mesh1D**, **Mesh2D**, **Mesh3D**. I want to write a function which differs only minimally for **Mesh1D**, **Mesh2D** and **Mesh3D**. Therefore, to avoid code redundancy, I am thinking of writing that function in the superclass and then call this function from within the subclasses. The simplified case:

**Mesh.m**

```
classdef (Abstract) Mesh < handle
   properties (Abstract)
     prop;
   end
   methods (Abstract)
     % Some abstract methods
   end
   methods
     function assemble(obj, other_parameters)
        % Do something
     end
   end
end
```

**Mesh1D**

```
classdef Mesh1D < Mesh
   properties
     prop;
     % Other properties
   end
   methods
     function assemble(obj)
     % Preprocessing steps
     assemble@Mesh(other_parameters) % call the superclass method
     % Postprocessing steps
   end
end
```

However, it produces the error: `'assemble' is not an accessible method of base class 'Mesh'.` What is the problem?

Comment: Can you post an [mcve]?

Comment: From what I get if I run your example I would say you have to pass obj as well in Mesh1D, so basically saying `assemble@Mesh(obj, otherparameters)`

Comment: Sorry, at home (on a slightly different version of the program) it works. Perhaps I was too tired. Tomorrow, I check it and if it works, the question can be deleted.

Comment: I checked it and it works as it should be. The moderator can delete this question, since this question serves no value, there is no trick in it, just do as the documentation suggests (the same as @lhcgeneva suggested).